# After calling setEnabled(false) button still can be pressed one more time

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, buttonclick

When clicking a button I immediately call `setEnabled` to false however this does not disable the button and I have to press again to disable.

I have tried to put `setEnabled` in different places but with the same result.

```
chooseLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseLeft.setEnabled(false);
                chooseRight.setEnabled(true);
                docRefPosts.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if(!chooseRight.isEnabled())
                                docRefPosts.update("votesForRight", FieldValue.increment(-1));
                            docRefPosts.update("votesForLeft", FieldValue.increment(1));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        chooseRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                chooseRight.setEnabled(false);
                docRefPosts.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if(!chooseLeft.isEnabled())
                                docRefPosts.update("votesForLeft", FieldValue.increment(-1));
                            docRefPosts.update("votesForRight", FieldValue.increment(1));
                        }
                    }
                });
                chooseLeft.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

It should function as a radio button where once selected only one can be chosen at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and I only have a guess as to why it is working. What I did was move all the code for the `OnCompleteListener` into a separate method. I think that the listener was running before the app could register `setEnabled(false)`. If anyone has any thoughts on this reasoning I would love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `setClickable(false)` as well if you wish to negate button click

```
chooseLeft.setClickable(false);
chooseLeft.setEnabled(false);
chooseRight.setClickable(true);
chooseRight.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: It is still acting the same way.

Comment: Also I believe that ```setClickable``` and ```setEnabled``` do similar things, the only difference being that ```setClickable``` does not change the appearance of the button.

Comment: okay question may i ask what is the behavior that you have on mind ? as a cycle
1. open the app , choose left , choose right , close the app , open it again ?